upload multiple files to the server using RxJs with result of each response coming before next iteration
I am trying to upload multiple files to the server sequentially. Before the next iteration, I want the result of the first iteration. I have tried many solutions with RxJS especially with concatMap with no luck.
I ended up using async method and await each response, before going to the next iteration as shown below. I would be keen to see if it is possible to achieve with purely Rxjs.
private getDocumentData(files: any): void {
    this.myService.getDoc(this.id))
        .pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$))
        .subscribe(document => {
        this.uploadMultipleFiles(document, files);
    });
}

async updateDoc(document: any, files: any) {
    for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        let updatedDocObj = {
            ...document,
            file: {
                date: files[i].lastModified,
                fileName: files[i].name,
            },
        };
        const success = await this.myService.uploadMultipleFiles(
            updatedDocObj,files[i]);
    }
}


updated. comes from a different method which gets information from API

here is a rxjs only approach of save data sequentially and use the last data in the next call?


export class Site7Component {
  private readonly data = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Max', value: 100 },
    { id: 2, name: 'Moritz', value: 200 },
    { id: 3, name: 'Franz', value: 300 },
  ];

  ngOnInit(): void {
    from(this.data)
      .pipe(
        concatMap((item) => this.saveData(item)),
        scan((acc, curr) => [...acc, this.doSth(acc, curr)], [] as any[])
      )
      .subscribe((result) => {
        console.log(result);
      });
  }

  private saveData(data: any): Observable<any> {
    return new Observable((observer) => {
      //place for the HTTP CALL
      setTimeout(() => {
        observer.next(data);
        observer.complete();
      }, 1000);
    });
  }

  private doSth(acc: any[], curr: any): any {
    console.log(acc);
    if (!acc || !acc[acc.length - 1]) {
      return curr;
    }
    return { ...curr, value: curr.value * (acc[acc.length - 1].id + 5) };
  }
}




Why use setTimeout? What if data hasn’t saved within a second?

@gables20 Timout is just my version of an async call. You probably have a REST CALL there. I just needed something that "takes time" in the example
